# Write in a Excel file with PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Well, I would like to write in an Excel file using a PHP script.
Actually, when an user submit the form, we get the mail and the current date in order to put it in the Excel.

The mail must be in one column, and the date too.

So this is my form (a classic form):

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
    <label for="name">Nom*<br />
        <input id="name" type="text" name="Nom" />
    </label><br /><br />

    <label for="mail">Mail*<br />
        <input id="mail" type="email" name="Email" />
    </label><br /><br />

    <label for="tel">Téléphone*<br />
        <input id="tel" type="text" name="Téléphone" />
    </label><br /><br />

    <label for="comment">Commentaire*<br />
        <textarea id="comment" type="text" name="Commentaires">    </textarea>
    </label><br /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
</form>
```

And my mail.php, so this is here that I use PHPExcel classes :

```
<?php
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/** PHPExcel */
include './Classes/PHPExcel.php';

/** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 */
include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';
include './Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

/* Set the variables */
$mail = $_POST['Email'];

// Line number
$ligne = 1;

// Excel object
$fichier = new PHPExcel();
$fichier->getProperties()->setCreator("Don't know");
//Set the size
$fichier->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(30);
$fichier->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(30);

$fichier->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$feuille = $fichier->getActiveSheet();

function writeExcel($objExcel, $sheet, $email){
    $sheet->SetCellValue('A'.$ligne, $email);
    $sheet->SetCellValue('B'.$ligne, date("Y-m-d H:i"));
    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objExcel);
    $objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
    $ligne++;
}

writeExcel($fichier, $feuille, $mail);
?>
```

I think it's the line number is a problem, I don't know how to organize my code.
Each time a user submit the form, we put his mail (cell A1) and the current date (cell B1), and the next mail must be at A2 cell, etc ...

I don't know if you know what I mean ^^

**EDIT**
With the comments I modified my code ! But it's the same ^^

```
<?php
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/** PHPExcel */
include './Classes/PHPExcel.php';

/** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 */
include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';
include './Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

/* Set the variable */
$mail = $_POST['Email'];

// Load file if it doesn't exists
if (file_exists("mail.xlsx"))
{
    $fichier = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("mail.xlsx");
}
else
{
    $fichier = new PHPExcel();
}
// Line number
$ligne = $fichier->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow() + 1;

// Excel object
$fichier->getProperties()->setCreator("Don't know");

//Set the size
$fichier->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(30);
$fichier->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(30);

$fichier->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$feuille = $fichier->getActiveSheet();

// Line number
global $ligne = $fichier->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow() + 1;

function writeExcel($objExcel, $sheet, $email){
    $sheet->SetCellValue('A'.global $ligne, $email);
    $sheet->SetCellValue('B'.global $ligne, date("Y-m-d H:i"));
    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objExcel);
    $objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
    global $ligne++;
}

writeExcel($fichier, $feuille, $mail);
?>
```

**LAST EDIT (I HOPE)**
Ok it's working :D

This is my code :

```
<?php
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/** PHPExcel */
include './Classes/PHPExcel.php';

/** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 */
include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';
include './Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

/* Set the variable */
$mail = $_POST['Email'];

// Load file if it doesn't exists
if (file_exists('mail.xlsx'))
{
    $objExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('mail.xlsx');
}
else
{
    $objExcel = new PHPExcel();
}

$objExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Don't know");

//Set the size
$objExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(30);
$objExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(30);

$objExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet = $objExcel->getActiveSheet();

// Line number
$line = $objExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow() + 1;

/*
    This function write in the Excel file.
    Note that the variables are passed by reference.
*/
function writeExcel(&$objExcel, &$sheet, $email, &$line){
    $sheet->SetCellValue('A'.$line, $email);
    $sheet->SetCellValue('B'.$line, date("Y-m-d H:i"));
    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objExcel);
    $objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
}    

writeExcel($objExcel, $sheet, $mail, $line);
?>
```

Comment: I think your function should be function writeExcel(&$objExcel, &$sheet, $email){//your code }

Comment: Can I ask why put "&" ?

Comment: `$ligne` is out-of-scope inside the `writeExcel()` function

Comment: var $ligne outside of function so use global $ligne before use.

Comment: But if you want to be continually updating the spreadsheet for each user request, then you only use `new PHPExcel` for the very first request, and you'll need to reload that file for each subsequent request to update it.... not good if you have multiple users trying to do this at the same time.... and Excel spreadsheet really isn't  good substitute for a database

Comment: Oh yes, I forgotten to put global $ligne ! Thanks :) Mark Baker it's not a database, it's just a file with 2 data, and I don't know what the client would like to do with that ^^

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap - There's no need to use `&` at all; these are all objects that are passed "by reference" as a pointer to the object, not "by value"

Comment: @MarkBaker It's exactly my problem. How with my existing code can I update the same Excel file ?

Comment: Instead of `$fichier = new PHPExcel();`.... check if file_exists(); if it does, load it and assign it to `$fichier` (`$fichier = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(<filename>);`) else `$fichier = new PHPExcel();`

Comment: And instead of `$ligne=1` use `$ligne = $fichier->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow() + 1;`

Comment: Ok, I don't understand all your code but with the doc it's will be fine. Thank you ! Ah I knew that we could get the highest row !!! ^^ :)

Comment: Could someone tell me what's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to learn about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in PHP. As noted in the comments, this is where your main problem lies.

You also need to read up exactly how you use the `global` keyword, as you clearly have misunderstood this. Well... I'd really recommend not using it at all instead, as it is generally considered a **bad thing**!
I recommend that you use the technique called [pass by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) instead, which is the answer to your question for the first comment.

Lastly, please, *please*, write your code in English. Not only for our sake, the people trying to help you, but also for your own (and employers) sake later on. Seeing variable and function names in a language you don't understand seriously hampers ones ability to understand the code, and thus increases the probability of errors occurring. Always assume that other people will need to look at, and understand, your code!

Comment: By "variable scope" do you mean my $ligne is bad defined ? If it's so bad to use `global` then what could I use ? My code IS in english, just the name's variables are in French ... BUT, I will put all my code in english, right ^^

Comment: THAT'S OK ! Thank you, really thank you for all ... However, your first link doesn't work ^^

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. Also, fixed the link, so it should point to the correct page. As for what one should use instead of "global": You can use pass by reference, as I noted. However, most of the time it is far better to restructure your code, so that you do not need to rely upon the functions to modify parameters passed to them. In this case, by incrementing the line number before you call the function. Also the $objExcel should preferably be returned, not passed by reference. The less you use passing by reference, and `global`, the less chance for unintended consequences.